# How to return as many elements(html tags) from function as the number passed to the function is ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and an icon library where I found filled stars (`FaStar`) and empty stars (`FaRegStar`). I created a function where I pass a number (1-5) and depending on this value my function should return the appropriate number of filled stars.

```
const getStars = (rate) => {
        if (rate <= 1) {
            return (<>
                <FaStar />
                <FaRegStar />
                <FaRegStar />
                <FaRegStar />
                <FaRegStar />
            </>
            )
        }
        else if (rate <= 2) {
            return (<>
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaRegStar />
                <FaRegStar />
                <FaRegStar />
            </>
            )
        }
        else if (rate <= 3) {
            return (<>
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaRegStar />
                <FaRegStar />
            </>
            )
        }
        else if (rate <= 4) {
            return (<>
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaRegStar />
            </>
            )
        }
        else if (rate <= 5) {
            return (<>
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
                <FaStar />
            </>
            )
        }
    }
```

While it works, it doesn't look good, do you have any ideas on how to return as many filled stars as the value provided?

Comment: @JabalLogian - The OP is notified of all answers that are posted. Pinging them a second time is not useful, and asking for votes is generally considered poor form. (That's a good answer, though!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build two arrays, then render those; be sure to handle [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) correctly:

```
const getStars = (rate) => {
    const faStars = Array.from({length: rate}, (_, index) =>
        <FaStar key={"star" + index} />
    );
    const faRegStars = Array.from({length: 5 - rate}, (_, index) =>
         <FaRegStar key={"regstar" + index} />
    );
    return <>{faStars}{faRegStars}</>;
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const {Fragment, useState, useEffect} = React;

const FaStar = () => <span>★</span>;
const FaRegStar = () => <span>☆</span>;

const getStars = (rate) => {
    const faStars = Array.from({length: rate}, (_, index) =>
        <FaStar key={"star" + index} />
    );
    const faRegStars = Array.from({length: 5 - rate}, (_, index) =>
         <FaRegStar key={"regstar" + index} />
    );
    // Note: Stack Snippets don't support <> fragments,
    // only the old verbose kind
    return <Fragment>{faStars}{faRegStars}</Fragment>;
};

const Example = () => {
    const [stars, setStars] = useState(1);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setStars(s => (s % 5) + 1);
        }, 800);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
        };
    }, []);
    return <div>{getStars(stars)}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I've used two arrays there, but you can do it with one array as well, as [shown by moonwave99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860005/157247). Doesn't really matter either way in terms of the work that gets done (not that that matters with arrays this small anyway), but each approach suits a different mental model.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two arrays, one for `<FaStar/>` and the other for `<FaRegStar/>`), using `[...Array(rate)]` and `[...Array(5-rate)]`.

Then map both arrays using `map` function and return the corresponding component. Don't forget to add `key={SOMETHING_UNIQUE}` if you return a view inside `map` function.

```js
const getStars = (rate) => (
    <>
        {
            [...Array(rate)].map((item, index) => (
                <FaStar key={index}/>
            ))
        }
        {
            [...Array(5-rate)].map((item, index) => (
                <FaRegStar key={index}/>
            ))
        }
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With just one loop:

```js
const getStars = (rate = 0, totStars = 5) => (
  <>
    {Array.from({ length: totStars },
      (_, index) => (index >= rate ? <FaRegStar key={`regstar-${index}`} /> : <FaStar key={`star-${index}`}/>)
    )}
  </>
);
```